# Custom Jackson object mapper for deserialization with the GraphQlClient

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-graphql

Is there any way I can provide a custom *ObjectMapper* to a Spring *GraphQlClient* to be used in deserialization of the response ?

I have  tried this, with no success

`HttpGraphQlClient.builder(client).codecConfigurer { c -> c.customCodecs().registerWithDefaultConfig(Jackson2JsonDecoder(mapper)) }.build()`